# What is the purpose of an Authentication Tag in AEAD encryption schemes?

Tags: authenticated-encryption

AEAD encryption schemes produce something referred to as an "authentication tag." What does this tag consist of, what is its purpose, and is the tag itself human-readable data such as a plaintext string or is it cipher text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of AEAD ciphers?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/what-is-the-advantage-of-aead-ciphers) If this answer does not satisfy you let us know.

Comment: The authentication tag is form of [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) or MAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does this tag consist of ... is the tag itself human-readable data

It will most likely be a string of random looking bits. It is not intended or required for humans to participate in the verification process.

> what is its purpose

The algorithm uses it to verify whether or not the ciphertext and/or associated data have been modified.

If either the ciphertext or associated data has been modified, then the procedure that re-computes the validation tag on the receiving end will end up generating a different tag. The algorithm will check the re-computed tag against the tag that was bundled with the ciphertext and associated data (which collectively can be referred to as a "cryptogram").

If the tags don't match, that means some part of the ciphertext and/or associated data have been modified.

If the tags do match, that means that no part of the ciphertext and/or associated data have been modified*

** at least, there is a a high probability assuming that the keys have not been compromised and the authentication scheme is secure*

Comment: Note: The exact procedure for generating and validating the tag may vary. Note2: *Why* we care about authentication tags is a different question.

Comment: But *generally* the tags are calculated though some MAC calculation. The results of MAC calculations are also commonly called "authentication tags" so the term is at least not unique to AEAD ciphers.